# Add an option to show only the badges I haven't yet earned

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

It would be nice if a checkbox could be added to the [/badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page, changing it from this:

> [image: a]

To something like this:

> [image: b]

It would make it a lot easier to see what badges I'm working towards!

Thoughts?

Comment: And what about the badges that you will never get? :P

Comment: I don't care about them two, keep showing them :p It's more to get rid of the long list of stuff that clutters up what I want to be able to immediately see.

Comment: who cares about badge those are always hard to get :P

Comment: This is a great idea, sure hope this FR gets more play.

Comment: I personally think this idea isn't that bad. What's up with the downvoting?

Comment: @ProfPickle I like it as well - I just think people disagree because it's one of those simple, small (very convenient!) features that aren't really conducive to making SE content itself higher quality.

Comment: This is now [status-complete] per the new Badges page, which has an "unearned" tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new badges page supports this feature. there is a earned/unearned tab for this purpose.

[image: earned]

[image: unearned]

Comment: It would be nice to have a checkbox, so I can view silver badges I don't have

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of this being rolled out on the site, I've written a nice little user script to do this.

You can get it from Stack Apps: [Hide badges I've already attained](https://stackapps.com/questions/4102/hide-badges-ive-already-attained)

#### — Before —

> [image]

#### — After —

> [image]

Comment: Very nice good sir!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if wee need this. But if, it is maybe better to add another filter to keep the interface clean:

[image]

Comment: With a checkbox though, we could still filter *all/gold/silver/bronze* (something that would be nice). With this solution we can't.

Comment: See my new answer.

Comment: @DannyBeckett - Actually the status is completed as per this suggestion. But I like your suggestion too. :)