# Can we neaten the tag listing in wildcard-tag search results?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, wildcards, sidebar

Introduced in 2009 was the ability to [add wildcards to favourite and ignored tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/). This is great, because it means I can favourite [css](/questions/tagged/css) *and* [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) with a single favourite tag.

The problem with this is the untidiness seen after clicking the tag to conduct a search.. In a search for `css*`, it includes 20 different CSS-related tags. This means that the "questions tagged" section of the sidebar shows:

[image: CSS* Example]

Considering all of these tags were expanded from one wildcard tag, can this instead be changed to just display the wildcard tag with a link to optionally show all the included tags? Something like:

[image: CSS* Request]

I suppose it's worth noting that the wildcard tag links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css* and not some crazily long search query.

Comment: Personally, I like seeing which tags are included.

Comment: And when you are not interested in `css-something-or-other`? Or a new technology that starts with `css` comes?

Comment: @DannyBeckett that's what the 'expand' link is for.

Comment: @Oded if you're not interested in something you'd ignore it.

Comment: You could write a trivial user script to do this...

Comment: ...or it could be implemented SE-wide, thus including users who don't spend their days hacking html.

Comment: @AndrewC You have a point, but I'm not sure how many non-programmers know about the wildcards.

Comment: Considerably more people know about * than know how to script a webpage, both in and out of the programming community.

Comment: @DannyBeckett The same could be said for some of your requests, Mr. [Checkbox to Hide Badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172613/checkbox-to-hide-badges-i-already-have)! ;-)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I'm sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: @DannyBeckett "you could write a trivial user script to do this" - was simply picking up on the fact that the same could apply to that request of yours along with many others here on Meta. Don't worry, I wasn't making a dig at you or anything.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly But I did exactly that... *confused*

Comment: @JamesDonnelly If you still haven't had any answers in the next day or 2, I'll write a user script for this too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as someone just gave this a downvote for whatever reason: This now no longer applies thanks to the [*new nav* update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation), meaning this question is now redundant.

Comment: Well, for those of us using new-nav, at least.

Comment: Are you sure? [I still see multiple tags listed when using wildcards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbPTH.png). (Not that I'm opposed to seeing multiple tags)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro you're using the old navigation. The new one replaces the wildcard search with a list of all the matching tags and shows nothing in the sidebar: http://i.imgur.com/2mrXZiq.png