# Asterisks (wildcards) do not work within [tag:name] markup

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, wildcards

Following on from [Can we neaten the tag listing in wildcard-tag search results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180646/can-we-neaten-the-wildcard-favourited-tag-search-result-tag-listing) I've noticed that the `[tag:name]` markup doesn't allow wildcards.

Tags link to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{tagName}`
Wildcard tags link to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{tagName}*`

[tag:css*]

This is similar to the (not fixed) URL issue: [A star in a URL breaks the linkification in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/a-star-in-a-url-breaks-the-linkification-in-posts). But you can fix URLs by using the HEX equivalent (`%2A`). This doesn't work here:

[tag:css%2A]

Comment: Why would you need it to allow them? A tag with a wildcard is _not_ a valid tag.

Comment: Depending on your definition of "tag", a wildcard is a valid favourite and ignored tag. http://i.imgur.com/rci8Xjl.png

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that actually works for searching and the like? Should've known that before I added 50 favorite tags to my profile hehe.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: But visiting the normal tag page with an asterisk in the tag name will automatically expand it to match all possible tags, such as with [css*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css%2A). Since the system knows what it is and handles it properly, it makes sense to allow them.