# Do Stack Exchange sites have an option of changing the default homepage?

Tags: support, homepage

Whenever I visit Stackoverflow, which I visit quite often, I see `interesting` questions on homepage. I would like to see `unanswered` questions or [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) instead of current default view. Not sure, if this feature already exist in Stackoverflow or not. So, can we change default view as per user preference?

Comment: Does it not remember it by default? Try changing your bookmark links?

Comment: There is a design effort on its way to change stuff. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation) what might be in store.

Comment: Bookmark option is nice! :)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, every tab and search on an SE site homepage corresponds to a unique URL that you can bookmark, which serves the same purpose. I don't see a need for SE to add some site-specific home page/bookmarking features.

Comment: Bookmark option is nice, but I thought if there is a feature then it would be better :)