# Maintain current Filter/Sort when clicking on a Tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, navigation, new-nav

With the [New Navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/158605), can we maintain the current view when clicking on a tag instead of resetting it?

My typical routine is to click "Unanswered > FavoriteTag", however now when I hit "needs answer > FavoriteTag" and it resets the selection to "new".

I could reverse my routine ("FavoriteTag > Needs Answer"), but then I'd need to click twice for each of my favorite tags instead of just once.

[image]

In addition, I can no longer filter a view further by clicking on a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.

Comment: This fix appears to have been reverted with the [most recent updates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261307/158605). Should I re-open this question, or open a separate question to report this bug?