# New navigation doesn't appear to alert of question changes when watching a tag

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, notifications, new-nav

I am watching the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag on Stack Overflow. My filter looks like this:

[image: Watching Python]

I do not receive notification of new questions. Previously I'd get notifications like this:

[image: Watching with notification]

This notification does work when watching the [main](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) page of Meta.

Are notifications only active for a certain set of filter options? If so, what are they? If not, can we get them back when watching pages other than the main page?

Comment: This is bothering me quite a bit.  I want my new questions.

Comment: Refreshing is not fun :( Notifications were *awesome*.

Comment: Related: [My question From MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297627/2173917). Updates, please.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, seems to be working for me now on SO and meta.so. I am happy now and would remove my dv from Sklivvz♦ if the answer is edited to allow me to.

The SE team is the best!

[image]

*gif courtesy of [DaveS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680506/dave-s)*

Comment: +1 for making room-15 do your gif work.

Comment: @McAdam331 is there any better place to have it done, Mac???

Answer (score -3):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.

Comment: There are reports that it's [not working](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297627/no-real-time-update-from-new-nav).

Comment: @Andy that is my post. Just to confirm your version here, it's not working till the time of this comment.

Comment: Sklivvz, you were caught [testing](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3610463#3610463) earlier, any chance you were able to replicate the bug that @SouravGhosh (and others in the MSO post) are still reporting?

Comment: It's fixed now. it was js caching on cloudflare

Comment: Can you please confirm with the configuration as mentioned in [this MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297627/2173917) ? I'm still facing the issue, maybe @Andy too. :-(

Comment: I am facing the issue, too...

Comment: *"It's fixed now"* no, no it isn't. *source: my finger is sore from all of the refreshing*

Comment: It is not fixed.