# Tweaks to the new expanded/collapse navigation view

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-nav

Could we have the ability to click on a question to toggle the expanded/collapsed view *on that question*? Rather than have it be a global toggle option? I'm thinking along the lines of how [Google News](http://news.google.com/) works (this could also include things like "Linked Questions" or "Related Questions" but I'll restrain myself for now). That way I can get more info on something that looks interesting without sacrificing screen real estate to less interesting things - this would also greatly increase my janitorial productivity (it would be a heck of a lot easier to quickly identify and flag low-quality questions).

[image]

But until then, can the option at least be persistent? Navigating away from the page currently forgets that I've selected the expanded view.

Comment: I can't see that... Also my tabs are different.

Comment: You have to opt in: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/188613

Answer (score 1):

We are not going to implement this at this point in time because it seems to give an uncertain gain, for a non-trivial amount of effort.

Comment: Boo. :( But is the ability to gain more context into a question on-demand without having to navigate away from your current page really "uncertain gain"? (Not trying to be argumentative, just want to understand the decision a bit more)

Comment: Basically, some people prefer to see a lot of titles, and, say open a few links in separate tabs; some other people prefer to see the context on the page, but at that point the full fat expanded version requires less clicks. The cost is very high because we need to change a number of things including e.g. realtime notifications.