# Add text next to the featured question (bounty) count?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties, navigation, new-nav

For the [new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/158605), can we get some text next to the Bounty #?

I couldn't find bounty questions at first until I hovered over the blue square that looked like it was some kind of admin tool.

[image]

What's the point of posting a bounty if its not easy for people to find/view the featured question list? :)

Comment: Whilst we do appreciate that the current UI can be improved, and also appreciate the feedback (in other words *the problem* you describe), simply going back to a "featured" tab is off the table for now (which is why I am declining *the solution* you propose) :-) The purpose of this prototype/alpha is to explore different possibilities.

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks for the reply. Is there another alternative you are considering to give Bountied questions more visibility? Or should I open another [discussion] question about it? With the new navigation style, I feel the visibility of bountied questions is greatly reduced.

Comment: If you have ideas to suggest feel free to open a new [feature-request] or [discussion] about it (maybe with [new-nav] and [design] to get the right eyes on it).

Comment: @Sklivvz Sure, I've opened a discussion for this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257016/158605). Also, can you explain or link to an explanation on why the "featured" link in the header area is not considered an option?

Comment: @Sklivvz - What broad set of approaches would you be willing to consider to as solutions the problem described here?

Answer (score 3):

I agree, there should be text next to the featured question (bounty) count. It should also be moved back to its original location.

[image]

If I am a relatively new user, or am not used the bounty system, and I see this layout, it is hard to recognize where to go to answer bountied questions.

This is a problem because creating a bounty costs reputation and is seen as a sort of premium path to getting a question answered and now it is no longer front and center.

Literally, front and center in the page is where the bounties used to be

[image]

This is where a user's eyes will naturally focus before they track to other parts of the page. It also includes the word "featured" which is inviting to click.

Removing this aspect of the bounty system is going to greatly diminish the effect and utility of bounties. There is a bunch of room available in the tabs, and I see absolutely no reason to obfuscate the bounty link into a little blue bubble off to the side. It should be front and center again, between new and popular.

[image]