# How can we increase visibility of bountied questions with the new navigation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, bounties, new-nav

Previously, bountied questions were available from any question page (including the home page) via the clearly labeled "featured" tab.

[image]

I think I actually discovered bounties originally because I was curious what was a "Featured" question was.

With the [new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing), I feel bountied questions have a lot less visibility. They are only indicated by the little blue square in the navigation bar (which I think looks like some kind of admin tool), or by going to the "needs answer" tab and changing the "Show" dropdown.

[image]

I opened a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256867/158605) asking to add the text back to the tab for bountied items, however the [official response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256867/add-text-next-to-the-featured-question-bounty-count?noredirect=1#comment838259_256867) is

> Simply going back to a "featured" tab is off the table for now (which is why I am declining the solution you propose) :-)

So this question is to try to get ideas about what else we could do to improve the visibility of bountied questions in the new navigation system.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd mentioned increasing visibility during the initial discussion of the new navigation. There is a discussion in the comments under my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251122/186281).

Comment: Thought you might find [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257433/not-all-bountied-questions-appear-in-bounties-list) interesting, as it relates to this question directly.

Answer (score 8):

What about adding a link somewhere in the navigation header that's inside of every question tab?

It would be on every question tab, there's enough space to add some descriptive text, and you could remove that blue admin-tool looking box from the tab headers that looks so out of place.

Some examples showing the "featured" link in separate places in the filter area of a question tab:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this seems to worsen it, by making it only visible once you're in that tab and not always. Likewise is this unintuitive, since the bountied questions are actually part of the "need answer" tab (and this is correct IMHO), so having this link in the "new" tab seems inconsistent. Even if it's in every question tab (including "need answer") it's still unintuitive when the link suddenly results in another tab opening for some tabs.

Comment: @ChristianRau Sorry if I was unclear, the link would be available for *all* question tabs, not just the New one.

Comment: @ChristianRau But you are right, I never noticed that it changes your tab to the "needs answer" tab when you click that icon. Hrm this suggestion might require more thought. Personally I think the "featured"  text should be placed on the top-level tab like [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256867/158605), however that was declined for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: I've never really seen the top level links as "tabs" before though... I've always viewed them as links to some of the most common filters/views of the question list. I think today is the first day I've really paid attention to the fact they're actually tabs, with different content in each one.

Comment: None of the examples shows views with tag filters available, that would probably reduce the space.

Comment: @Sklivvz True, but you could always reduce the text to "featured" or get rid of it entirely depending on how much space is available. I think having it as part of the header area on a tab is better than having it in the upper-right corner of the content where you'd typically expect to find admin-type links

Answer (score 3):

For the question, two key points: 
1.highlight bountied questions 2. Do not conflict with simply style in new navigation. Bounty is to get more attention on Questions,so if '**need answer**' highlight with traditional blue, means there're '**bounties**' in '**need  blue highlight, means no '**bounties**' in 'need answer'.
[image]

Comment: For me, just highlighting something blue would not indicate anything out of ordinary or make me want to seek out why it was highlighted blue

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that bounties need more visibility. My suggestion would be to Change the `Need Answer` title (the text to the far left of the tabs) to `Need Answer & Bounties`. There's plenty of room for a longer title.

Comment: I think that would be a good idea providing it's not too long, although I like the idea best if combined with [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257017/158605) of a highlighted link within the nav bar to quickly and easily access bounties. Also, I'd want the blue bounty # kept as well to see how many bounties there were at all times. It's especially nice when browsing tags that don't have many bounties