# Incorrect number of bounties in the top bar link

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, new-nav, active-bounties

I just happened to see on the `new` tab that there seem to be 12 bounties. But when clicking the `12 bounties` link the actual bounties list only shows 7:

[image]

After this the bounties link always says there are 7 bounties, even when I return to the `new` tab and click around through the various other tabs.

I first tended to shrug that off as some kind of caching problem, but after some time the bounties link yet again said there are 12, only to revert to 7 again when clicking on it. There even was a situation where the `need answers/bounties` page listed 12 bounties, only to revert to 7 once I clicked through to one of the bountied questions.

But this all seems very non-deterministic and hard to reproduce and I'm not sure if it is just because 5 of the bounties coincidentally ended just recently.

Comment: I blame caching... it is on-and-off 7 or 12 for all kind of click-paths I follow...

Comment: @rene After learning that those 5 questions actually have answers while the others don't, I'd rather blame the "need answers" tab being botched right now to only show questions without answers. Because if you select "all", it doesn't show any questions with 0-score unaccepted answers (i.e. "unanswered" in SE sense), at least on the entire first page, but only those without *any* answer, which is clearly a bug, too.

Comment: I think that analysis might be correct

Comment: Oh my, after looking a bit more into the "need answer" tab, it seems completely blown to bits, seeing that filtering by "all" and sorting by "recently active" shows the most recently active question being modified on Jul 20, which can't be in any reasonable definition of that tab/filter combination. Unfortunately that makes it hard to file any additional bugs, since they all come down to *"the 'need answers' tab is entirely broken"*, and since nobody really knows [what the options inside that tab are supposed to show *exactly*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256947/162011) anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau "need answers" has been updated. Sklivvz just did [status-completed] on my [Confusion about need answers...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261355/confusion-about-need-answers-no-answer-sorting-options-at-meta-se-new-naviga)

Comment: @ChristianRau do u still see the bounties mismatch? Here is what I see [imgur screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NtvzVAD.png)

Comment: @ChristianRau well the bug may be still there for some users as Sklivvz added [status-reproduced] tag to this. +1 for bringing up this issue

Comment: Stop stealing [my questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257433/not-all-bountied-questions-appear-in-bounties-list). :(