# No bounties on StackOverflow!

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, active-bounties

The new navigation doesn't show the bounties on the main page. It always displays *0 bounties*:

> [image: no bounties]

While other pages do show the bounty number correctly:

> [image: 434 bounties]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: [Cache](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259323/152859)? lol.

Comment: If there was one time there were no bounties on SO, but I doubt that.

Comment: It was ironic, dev blaming cache when it's 99% not cache. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in builds `3790` (meta) and `2910` (main).