# Is the badges tab necessary?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

Whenever I want to do something with badges, I go to my profile, where I can view which badges I have and my progress towards new badges. I've never clicked on the badges navigation tab unless by accident.

[Stack Exchange is currently redesigning its navigation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing), and it might be worth considering removing the badges navigation tab altogether. I can't think of a reason for its existence, and removing it would simplify the experience and reduce clutter.

If anyone needs to access the badges page, it would still be available through the help center.

For the visually inclined:

[image: remove the badges tab and reduce clutter!]

Comment: We're not really redesigning the entire nav system, although some of that is a (hopefully positive?) side-effect. The main goal of the questions nav changes is to make it easier for folks to find *questions* they are interested in.

Comment: Sure, also nuke the Questions tab, Users tab, Tags tab. Leave only Ask Question.

Comment: Badges? We don't need no _stinking_ badges!

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion it's useful.

It's the only place (at least that I'm aware of) that gives you one-click access to a page where you can easily see what badges you don't have and a summary of the descriptions of all the badges you do (and don't) have, which I personally find useful.

If it went away I'd hope it would be replaced by a one-click link to that page on the profile page instead.

Currently, to access that page through the help center, the path is *Help → Help Center → View the list of badges* (thanks Scimonster). To access from the profile page it's about the same: either *Badges → Click any badge → click Badges on the right*, or *Click the "newest badge" badge → Learn More → Click Badges on the right*. Maybe there's a shorter path, and these aren't *too* bad, but in any case without the "Badges" link it feels kind of complicated to go from "I'd like to see a list of badges" to the actual page, I'd always feel like I was randomly clicking things until I finally get to the page.

On the other hand I may totally be missing some alternate existing quick access path that invalidates everything I just typed.

Comment: You can just do Help -> Help center -> View the list of badges, but i still like having a direct link.