# New navigation page should hide closed/duplicated/on-hold questions at the "need answer" tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

The [new navigation page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) is currently showing [closed], [duplicated] and [on hold] questions at the **need answer** tab. My suggestion is to hide them since they can't be answered.

Sorting by "votes" at SO, we see tons of [duplicated] questions filling almost the entire first page. This way is harder to find good questions (*= high upvoted*) to answer.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: It's not that they are just duplicate, but they also appear to be merged. I didn't dig deep to see if there are unmerged but duplicate questions or not, though. IMO, closed questions of any kind should not show up under "need answer" since they can't be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done and will be released in the next deployment.

The "popular" lists will not show any closed questions.

Comment: What should I expect? Does this only affect merged questions? Closed as duplicate of? All closed questions?

Comment: @Sklivvz, sorry, but I believe that this question is not [status-completed]. You've hide duplicates from the "popular" tab, but we've asked to hide from the "need answer" tab. Shouldn't this question receive [status-planned]?

Comment: @Sklivvz, thank you! New-nav version 2 implemented the same for the "need answer" tab. Now the question is [status-complete].