# Sometimes a SyntaxError is logged to console while viewing questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, advertising, javascript

I am not sure if it is related to the Stack Exchange network, but the Developer Tools in Chrome sometimes log an `Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse` while viewing questions on Stack Overflow. The SyntaxError is related to the file ados.js which I think belongs to adzerk.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse
  JSON.parse @ ados.js:3
  impressionData @ ados.js:443
  root.ados_writePixel @ ados.js:753
  pixel_command__15905 @ ados?t=1439202202176&request={"Placements":[{"A":22,"S":8277,"D":"adzerk639078980","ATA":[17,2221],…:5
  root.azLoad @ ados.js:208  
  (anonymous function) @ ados?t=1439202202176&request={"Placements":[{"A":22,"S":8277,"D":"adzerk639078980","ATA":[17,2221],…:9
```

How to reproduce (only for those who have the [New Navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation) in place):

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive
2. Open Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>
3. Open a question from the List → An Uncaught SyntaxError may be written to console
4. If no SyntaxError is logged → Navigate back by clicking on Stack Overflow icon and retry at Step 3

Comment: A link to the question could be useful. Or it is completely random?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Its not a specific question. But for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915928/deserializing-xml-to-dataset-datatable i could reproduce it

Comment: That sounds like it is coming from our 3rd party ad provider, although I cannot reproduce what you are seeing; somewhat vexing, but also probably out of our hands. I wonder - is it possible this is due to local interception by a work proxy, adblock, or some other tool trying to protect you from ads?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have no adblocker installed in Chrome. I´m not sure if my company network blocks some ads. But I think not. I will try to reproduce it from home

Comment: @Jehof I can repro but not consistently, and I can't isolate the cause just yet. Note I can't repro it at /questions?show=all&sort=active, only at /questions?sort=active.

Comment: We are digging into this on the adzerk side - it looks like a bug in our logging code that is only triggered in some instances. Once we have it resolved I will leave an answer.

Comment: Do you remember seeing any specific ad when it happened? Might be a single "corrupted" ad. /cc @stevvve.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There are no ads at all. The only one is from careers "Looking for a job?".

Comment: hmm... I see the link you posted works only for new nav. I get Page Not Found error, so can't really try and repro.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, I didn't see a connection between a specific ad and the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been fixed on our side (Adzerk, I'm the Founder and CEO) - we recently added events to our client-side JavaScript and when de-serializing some records it was failing. This was due to the fact that we use a modified BASE64 (that will work on our URLs) and we weren't correctly de-modifying it before we tried to decode it.

It didn't cause any issues - other than some console messages (which I know are annoying!)