# What is holding back the new navigation from rolling out to graduated sites?

Tags: discussion, new-nav, navigation

It's high time to bury the old navigation in my opinion.

[image]

The [iteration on the great cheese move](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation) appears to have ground to a halt now that MSE, SO and MSO have received the cleaner navigation.

I personally strongly prefer the new nav for slicing through questions, seeing which I can/should answer. The new/active/featured/hot/week/month views are counterproductive to me on the site I spend most of my time and I feel we would get better answer coverage if the changes I see would get rolled out to Ask Different. *That being said, what's perceived as good change for one site might not be the best for the network as a whole.*

Is there further debate that this iteration is bad/harmful?

If not, what is holding back this change from being rolled out to the rest of the network?

Comment: It's high time to bury the **new** navigation, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We care a lot about the feedback we get. Sometimes it needs ...interpretation, but it's useful nonetheless.

We're being a bit slow because holidays, but here's what we are working on:

1. A simpler UI for newbies which "grows with your experience"
2. The ability to save your searches
3. User on-boarding, useful both for introducing the features to alpha users and for new users
4. Different versions of the new nav for anonymous users, for mobile users and network sites (at the moment they all see the old version).

I am not sure which of these we will be able to ship this iteration, but many of these things need to be finished before we roll out this live. We definitely want to avoid making major changes to the UI once a lot of users have gotten used to it.

Comment: Thank you  - knowing that work is active makes the waiting a bit more tolerable. I just feel strongly that iteration is good and that the "always be shipping" mantra would be good here to avoid getting too much change wrapped into one gigantic release.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is wise to not implement the new navigation network-wide since it isn't ready yet.

Many *experienced* users from across the network have tested it and many returned to the old navigation since it is hard to understand, illogical, and less intuitive then the old navigation.

I share that feeling and I have trouble getting used to the new navigation. I think they should have some more iterations to make it better and *then* deploy it.

Comment: Thanks - All I saw was the upside. If a significant proportion of people are rejecting it after trying it, then it's good it's not rolled out.

Comment: Bikeshedding: the overwhelming majority of users like the new nav. *A small minority of users* have concerns and very few users have stopped using it.