# Searching for unanswered questions with more than one tag yields wrong results

Tags: bug, tags, search, unanswered-questions

I'm trying to find unanswered questions with both `kotlin` and `gradle` tags like this: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/kotlin+gradle

It shows many questions without `kotlin` tag which is unexpected.

All questions with url like `/questions/tagged/kotlin+gradle` works correctly.

Comment: On the new-nav this works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin%20gradle?filter=need-answers&mode=all

Comment: I have no idea what `new-nav` is, may be I need to toggle some setting? The link you provided doesn't work for me. It shows only questions with both tags, but includes answered questions.

Comment: Another case is `[kotlin] -[android]`, it yields zero questions while there clearly are (http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/kotlin+-android)

Comment: Workaround (partial) is to include `answers:0` into search query instead of using "unanswered"

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation

Comment: See answer on dupe: "The tags in the unanswered section are joined by a OR to be consistent with the default behavior of that section".

Answer (score 0):

It has been made clear that using the phrases: *[kotlin][gradle]* (tags that have "kotlin" **or** "gradle"), *kotlin+gradle* (tags that have in them "kotlin" **and** "gradle"), *kotlin+gradle* (all search terms that have "kotlin" **and** "gradle") do not show only unanswered questions.

I think this is because the unanswered page description says "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers tagged with", that is, it mixes questions with no upvotes **and** no accepted answers, so at the moment, there is no clear way to separate this list into **only** unanswered questions.

In short, there is **no official way** to do what you asked for, unless you use @Ilya's workaround.

Note: I put [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/scala+monads) to show demonstrate how the site mixes other types of questions with unanswered questions, and also to show that it works for other keywords as well.

Comment: Not relevant. When adding a search term (i.e. typing anything that is not a tag in the search box), the user is redirected to the general tag search/page, and leave the Unanswered section, which the question here is all about.

Comment: I don't think that the OP is asking anything that is not a tag, but the OP wants to know how to search for questions that are tagged with **multiple tags combined together**. If this is not their intent, then can you please support your claim with evidence?

Comment: "I'm trying to find **unanswered** questions" - see bold part. There is whole section on SO for unanswered questions, separate from the ordinary questions section, and that's the point.

Comment: Edited my post @ShadowWizard.

Comment: Never mind, you miss my point and I can't explain it any better.